# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade boot problems

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, grub2, upgrade

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I have a boot in problem. When starting the Computer, it first produces a orange rectangle (Ubuntu Colour), then a blank screen, and nothing else. When I then press the Reset key of the Computer, it comes up with the GRUB menu, containing three items: Ubuntu; Advanced Options; Settings. Using the Ubuntu option produces a blank screen; Settings causes a reboot; Advanced Options go into a second level menu with two previous Ubuntu kernels, the first which does not boot either. The second does get me into Ubuntu.

I tried various things from the web, including an Ubuntu apt-get update, and apt-get upgrade, and a Grub 2 update and reinstall. Nothing worked. I even tried to make changes to the Grub2 configuration files, but with no success. I eventually did a boot repair using the Boot Repair tool. No success.

The Boot Info can be found at http://paste.ubuntu.com/9846884/.

The computer specification is here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/szkt7koxoaz8ks7/AABI-Z_eCoJQTcFoNcBqdL3ha?dl=0. This machine is one of two identical ones. I upgraded both. The other one has no problems.

I am really at wit's end. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few possibilities, but before you do anything, [make a system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)!  You've been promoted to user type 4!

Then:

1. You did make a system back-up, didn't you??? :P  ;-)
2. If both machines are identical, clone the working machine onto the non-working one.
3. Kernel Linux 3.8.0-29-generic works.  (deducted from your boot repair and description)

   Remove all peripherals, disable everything in the BIOS that you can disable (including the NVidia). Boot into that kernel, do an upgrade, reboot, and then start adding peripherals/turning things on one by one in the BIOS starting with the most critical one.

   *Reboot after every addition and go back to disabling/removing it when your system stops working.*
4. Re-install 14.04.1.

   Yeah, that's what everyone always says, right?

   But here there is a reason: *something somewhere* went wrong in the upgrade process and you've lost a week already.
   You've got a system back-up anyway, so *why try to find out what went wrong where?*  Just get on with it!  ;-)

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)